ReferenceError: document is not defined in nextjs
I am using zegocloud voice and video service to build video calling app. I have use nextjs framework and while building stage this page is occurring a document is not defined error in server side rendering. I have tried to solve the problem but I am still facing the issue
"use client";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { ZegoUIKitPrebuilt } from "@zegocloud/zego-uikit-prebuilt";
import { generateToken04 } from "@/config/token";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function randomID(len) {
  let result = '';
  const chars = '12345qwertyuiopasdfgh67890jklmnbvcxzMNBVCZXASDQWERTYHGFUIOLKJP';
  const maxPos = chars.length;
  len = len || 5;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * maxPos));
  }
  return result;
}

function Page() {
  const { data } = useSession();
  const roomID = useSearchParams()?.get("roomId"); // Ensure roomID is accessed correctly
  const userID = randomID(5);
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false); // Track if we're on the client

  useEffect(() => {
    // Only set the flag to true after the component has mounted on the client
    setIsClient(true);
  }, []);

  const myMeeting = async (element) => {
    if (!element || !isClient) return; // Ensure code only runs on the client

    const appID = parseInt(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ZEGO_APP_ID);
    const serverSecret = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ZEGO_SERVER_SECRET;
    const experationTime = 3600;

    try {
      const token = await generateToken04(appID, userID, serverSecret, experationTime);

      const kitToken = ZegoUIKitPrebuilt.generateKitTokenForProduction(
        appID,
        token,
        roomID,
        userID,
        data?.user?.name
      );

      const zp = ZegoUIKitPrebuilt.create(kitToken);

      // Start the call
      zp.joinRoom({
        container: element,
        sharedLinks: [
          {
            name: 'Copy link',
            url: `${window.location.origin}${window.location.pathname}?roomId=${roomID}`,
          },
        ],
        scenario: {
          mode: ZegoUIKitPrebuilt.GroupCall, // Adjust as needed
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  // Render nothing on the server
  if (!isClient) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="-ml-14"
      ref={myMeeting}
      style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
    ></div>
  );
}

export default Page;


Please Help me to slove the error

Can you share more details like if you are using app router or page router? Are you using layout file..Alternatively  you can give it a try of create page file as a server component. and move the logic of client to another file.

I am using app router and yes I am using a layout file for the entire app
